# List Emails are tracking opens, but won't track the link clicks?

Tags: email

When users are sending out list emails in Salesforce (not regular emails, list emails the object) it is supposed to track opens and clicks, but right now it is only tracking the opens, not the clicks. Tracking is enabled, and everything else about the list email seems to be working well. Regular emails and Inbox emails are tracking the clicks, it's just the list emails that aren't.